# Difference between JS and .NET daylight saving behavior

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, date, dst

I am trying to get C# and JS generate the same results when adding minutes on JS `Date` and .NET `DateTime` objects.
My system is using the Greek culture settings, but most likely you will get similar results on your machines (if you play around with the values).
I have this JS code using moment.js:

```
var dt1 = new Date(2020, 0, 19, 0, 0, 0);
var m1 = moment(dt1);
[m1.toString(), m1.add(100980, 'minutes').toString()]

>  ["Sun Jan 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200", "Sun Mar 29 2020 04:00:00 GMT+0300"]
```

..and this C# code in LinqPad:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR"); //CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; //CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var dt = new DateTime(2020, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, ci.Calendar, DateTimeKind.Local);
dt.ToString("G", ci).Dump();
var dt2 = dt.AddMinutes(100980);
dt2.ToString("G", ci).Dump();

> 19/1/2020 12:00:00 πμ
> 29/3/2020 3:00:00 πμ
```

...and when printing with invariant culture:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR"); //CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; //CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var dt = new DateTime(2020, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, ci.Calendar, DateTimeKind.Local);
dt.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();
var dt2 = dt.AddMinutes(100980);
dt2.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();

> 01/19/2020 00:00:00
> 03/29/2020 03:00:00
```

Can someone tell why I get different results?
The system settings are the same and I have tried using both `CurrentCulture` and  `CreateSpecificCulture("el-GR")` without getting any similarity to the JS results.

I have even created my own `addMinutes()` in JS, but I still have the same issue.

It seems that JS does a daylight saving switch exactly at 100980 minutes after the start date (if you add 100979 minutes you will see that), but C# does not! According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country), the JS behavior is correct behavior. But I was pretty sure so far that .NET was correct as well. C# seems to do a switch 70.2 days before, according to a quick test that I have done.

Any ideas what I have to do in order to get the same results between the two languages when adding minutes to dates?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/), and it seems that it agrees with JavaScript:

```
var dt0 = new DateTime(2020, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0, 0, ci.Calendar, DateTimeKind.Local).AcServerToUtc();
Duration duration = Duration.FromMinutes(100980);
Instant start = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dt0.AcMakeKindUtc());
Instant future = start + duration; // Or now.Plus(duration)
var zone =  DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
future.InZone(zone).LocalDateTime.ToString("G", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();

> 03/29/2020 04:00:00
```

So, that seems a possible solution!

Comment: Give [noda time](https://nodatime.org/) a try - if has better time zone support then the CLR

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for the suggestion. I had heard about `nodatime` in the past. However, our code base is using the .NET Framework's functionality and it will be hard to switch, but I will certainly try it, just to see if anything changes. The weird thing is that we've never noticed anything wrong with the C# timezones/DST, so I was a bit skeptical on the idea that there is something wrong in C#'s functionality. I will update the question to share my results.

Comment: @stuartd Yep! `NodaTime` seems to agree with JavaScript, so it might be a good solution to switch to it. Thanks! Post an answer if you want, so that I can accept it. Or, if you want, I can write an answer myself.

Comment: You should post the update as an answer and accept it. However, it doesn't really answer the question of why the difference occurred or how to fix it in .NET without using a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `AddMinutes` call is being done on a `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Local`.  Despite being marked with this kind, *math* on a `DateTime` object doesn't take time zones into account.  *Even with local time*.

Since you're working with local kind, you can simply convert to UTC, do the math, then convert back.

```
var dt2 = dt.ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(100980).ToLocalTime();
```

You might also want to look into using the `DateTimeOffset` type instead, and performing time zone conversions with `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime`.

Comment: This looks interesting. Might be an alternative to using `NodaTime`. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `NodaTime`, as I have written above in the question update.

It still doesn't agree with `moment.js` all the times, but I feel it agrees more often to it.

I guess daylight saving is a big huge mess and no-one can handle it well enough.